# Why does Chrome add https to my site assets, safari and firefox work fine

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-chrome, ssl, https

I just visited my website and it appears to be broken, I started investigating viewing a source code and turns out when I view my site from Chrome it adds https to my stylesheets and javascript assets which is causing layout issues due to javascript not being properly loaded. It works fine on Safari and Firefox.

I am using wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style() function to include my css and js like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'osetin-feature-vote', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/osetin-feature-vote.js', array( 'jquery' ), OSETIN_FEATURE_VOTE_VERSION, true );
```

When I view a source code from chrome it shows that my JS and CSS files are trying to be loaded from https:// and they fail since I don't have ssl on my server, I can not login from Chrome as well, it tries to redirect me to https admin login as well.

The weirdest part is that Safari and Firefox work fine. I've checked the siteurl field in DB and it is correct, showing the http:// site address.

My site with issue: http://pluto.pinsupreme.com

Comment: What is a downvote about? It's a legitimate question

Comment: Maybe give more details about how you include your css/js? From _functions.php_, or in the header? And what about `siteurl` in `wp_options`, is the value correct?

Comment: Just checked in Chrome and your website is looking fine on my end - stylesheets and scripts are included in http (Chrome version 43.0.2357.134). Maybe check on a fresh new Chrome installation? Could be some plugin maybe. This could help too : http://superuser.com/a/881431

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue, turns out the sligthly outdated wooCommerce plugin was causing this issues by adding a filter which was forcing my site to use SSL. I've updated it to the latest version and it now seems to be working fine.